# Converting dates to hours in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a start and end date for individuals and i need to estimate if the time passed from the start to the end is within 2 days
or 3 plus days.These dates are assign to record ids, how can i filter ones that ended  within 2 days (from the start date)
and the ones that ended after 3 days or later.

```r
Record_id <- c("2245","6728","5122","9287")
Start <- c("2021-01-13 CST" ,"2021-01-21 CST" ,"2021-01-17 CST","2021-01-13 CST")
End <- c("2021-01-21 18:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 16:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 13:00:00 CST","2021-01-25 15:00:00 CST")
```

I tried using

```r
elapsed.time <- DF$start %--% DF$End
time.duration <- as.duration(elapsed.time)
```

but I am getting error because End date contains hour.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr pipe that will include both constraints (2 and 3 days):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(Start:End, as.POSIXct)) %>%
  mutate(d = difftime(End, Start, units = "days")) %>%
  filter(!between(difftime(End, Start, units = "days"), 2, 3))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Record_id Start               End                 d             
#   <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>        
# 1 2245      2021-01-13 00:00:00 2021-01-21 18:00:00  8.750000 days
# 2 6728      2021-01-21 00:00:00 2021-01-22 16:00:00  1.666667 days
# 3 5122      2021-01-17 00:00:00 2021-01-22 13:00:00  5.541667 days
# 4 9287      2021-01-13 00:00:00 2021-01-25 15:00:00 12.625000 days
```

I included `mutate(d=` so that we can see what the actual differences are. If you were looking to *remove* those, then use `filter(between(..))` (no `!`).

In the case of the data you provided, all observations are less than 2 or more than 3 days. I'll expand this range so that we can see it in effect:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(Start:End, as.POSIXct)) %>%
  mutate(d = difftime(End, Start, units = "days")) %>%
  filter(!between(difftime(End, Start, units = "days"), 1, 6))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Record_id Start               End                 d          
#   <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>     
# 1 2245      2021-01-13 00:00:00 2021-01-21 18:00:00  8.750 days
# 2 9287      2021-01-13 00:00:00 2021-01-25 15:00:00 12.625 days
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Record_id = c("2245", "6728", "5122", "9287"), Start = c("2021-01-13 CST", "2021-01-21 CST", "2021-01-17 CST", "2021-01-13 CST"), End = c("2021-01-21 18:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 16:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 13:00:00 CST", "2021-01-25 15:00:00 CST")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just converted the character to a date time with `lubridate` and then subtracted the dates. What you'll get back are days. I then filter for dates that are within 2 days.

```
Record_id<- c("2245","6728","5122","9287") 
Start<-c("2021-01-13 CST" ,"2021-01-21 CST" ,"2021-01-17 CST","2021-01-13 CST")
End<-c("2021-01-21 18:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 16:00:00 CST", "2021-01-22 13:00:00 CST","2021-01-25 15:00:00 CST")
df <- dplyr::tibble(x = Record_id, y = Start, z = End)
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(y:z), ~ lubridate::as_datetime(.)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(diff = as.numeric(z - y)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(diff <= 2 )
```

Comment: When using `as.numeric` on `POSIXt` or `Date` object differences, you should include `units="days"`; the default action is to pick the most reasonable units, so it might be seconds or days, depending on the observations.